# Dropdown not updating on Front End when I update database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

As the title says, I updated the 'name' column in my database in PHPmyadmin manually to something different.

```
@foreach ($channels as $channel)
                      <option value="{{ $channel->id}}" {{old('channel_id')==$channel->id? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $channel->name}}</option>
                                           @endforeach
```

But when I see the dropdown on my browser, it is displaying the old values not the new ones.

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what you already tried to fix it? Are you sure you are working on the correct record?

Comment: The functionality of my app is working properly. However the list in the dropdown menu in my browser reflecting the values in my database from the {{ $channel->name}} part of my code is still displaying the old value,s not the new ones I changed in my table in MYSQL.

Comment: You are 100% sure you are looking in the correct db and the correct record? As far as I know laravel does not cache DB values(out of the box). So the situation is impossible. What db-tool are you using? Maybe you need to 'commit' your db change?

Comment: I solved it by using  @foreach (App\Channel::all() as $channel)  instead. I hope nothing else blows up if I do this, I'm still quite new to Laravel.

Comment: Seems all right, but not best practise to do queries from a view tbh. How is `$channels` constructed?